# Why won't my mouse work with my laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, mouse

Ever since I updated Windows 10, my (wired) mouse hasn't worked with my laptop. When I plug it into any USB port, the computer doesn't react to it and the mouse doesn't light up. It doesn't work in safe mode, and attempting to reinstall drivers hasn't fixed the issue. The mouse works completely fine with my desktop computer, just not my laptop. When I boot in safe mode, the mouse lights turn on for a few seconds, and then the mouse dies again.

What on earth is going on?

Edit: The mouse I'm using is the UtechSmart Venus 16400 dpi.

Edit: While other mice work differently (see below), no mouse I have tried works.

Edit: Thanks to everyone for their suggestions, a comment below suggested a fresh copy of Windows 10 and that fixed it. Sorry for anyone in the future with a similar problem, but I couldn't find the cause.

Comment: Did you get the drivers from this page: http://www.utechsmart.com/download ?  Your model is shown there.

Comment: Yes, that's where I got them from.

Comment: Does a different mouse work?  Have you asked utechsmart Support?

Comment: I tried another mouse to test - if I plug it in slowly, the sensor light comes on but it doesn't work, and if I plug it in quickly, the sensor light flashes and turns off, and it doesn't work. As the problem isn't specific to this mouse I won't contact UtechSmart support.

Comment: Look in Control Panel, Device Manager, USB Controllers and open that to see the devices. Right click on each and select Update Drivers. Do that for all, restart the computer and see if a mouse connects

Comment: I have tried that, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: At this point, try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link. This updates all drivers as the repair progresses.  Start with the option to keep everything.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Although you couldn't find the cause of the issue, you could solve it. It worth posting it as an answer.

Comment: I have posted as you have suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the regular fixes that one might try did work for you, then at this point, try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link. This updates all drivers as the repair progresses. Start with the option to keep everything.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10